# Render a .NET Web Control from a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5, web-controls

Is it possible in ASP.NET to dynamically load up a *WebControl* from a string with some tag contents in it (without writing a bunch of custom code)?

For instance, I have a string like the following:

```
string controlTag = "<asp:Label ID=\"lblLabel\" runat=\"server\" />";
```

I then want to do something like the following to load up the control from that string:

```
WebControl webControl = LoadControlFromTagString(controlTag);
```

I can simply parse the string myself and dynamically load up a control in **LoadControlFromTagString**, but I was wondering if there is anything built in to .NET I can take advantage of.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you dynamically creating controls based on a string? Dynamically loading controls can be messy business and if you aren't familiar with viewstate you will probably run into problems.

Answer (score 7):

There are several choices, depending on what you want to do your control instance (and how much control you want over stuff like rendering, databinding, etcetera).

The easiest is probably [TemplateControl.ParseControl(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz3ffe28.aspx) which you have access to via your current Page instance.